# Add new column (or filter) based on multiple columns and satisfying multiple conditions

Tags: r, multiple-columns, multiple-conditions

This is a simplified example of the 'problem'

```
dt <- 
  read.table(textConnection("names age location
Ann  32     Glas
Annie  31       US
Anne  40     Glas
Kerri  31     Edin
David  39      Fra
Glas  29     Annie
Lindsay  24       US
Lynsey  37     Glas
Glas  Annie       US
Lila  39      Fra
Layla  37       US"), 
             header = TRUE, 
             sep = "", 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

I want to add a new column called AnnGlas for every row where "ann" and "glas" are both present

I know how to filter for either, but not both at the same time

```
dt %>% filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(str_to_lower(.), "glas|ann")))
```

I can find a match for either, but not both, using apply

```
apply(dt, 2, function(x) str_detect(str_to_lower(x), "glas|ann"))
```

I need to find some way of checking whether any row column contains glas, and if another contains ann, so that I can make the new column

The output would look like this

```
  names   age   location desc 
   <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <lgl>
 1 Ann     32    Glas     TRUE 
 2 Annie   31    US       FALSE
 3 Anne    40    Glas     TRUE 
 4 Kerri   31    Edin     FALSE
 5 David   39    Fra      FALSE
 6 Glas    29    Annie    TRUE 
 7 Lindsay 24    US       FALSE
 8 Lynsey  37    Glas     FALSE
 9 Glas    Annie US       TRUE 
10 Lila    39    Fra      FALSE
11 Layla   37    US       FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, we want both the terms should be present we can check both of them separately using `lapply` and `Reduce`. Checking the pattern together might result into giving an output as `TRUE` if only one of them is present in both the columns.

```
dt$desc <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(dt, grepl, pattern = "Glas")) & 
            Reduce(`|`, lapply(dt, grepl, pattern = "Ann"))

dt
# A tibble: 11 x 4
#   names   age   location desc 
#   <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <lgl>
# 1 Ann     32    Glas     TRUE 
# 2 Annie   31    US       FALSE
# 3 Anne    40    Glas     TRUE 
# 4 Kerri   31    Edin     FALSE
# 5 David   39    Fra      FALSE
# 6 Glas    29    Annie    TRUE 
# 7 Lindsay 24    US       FALSE
# 8 Lynsey  37    Glas     FALSE
# 9 Glas    Annie US       TRUE 
#10 Lila    39    Fra      FALSE
#11 Layla   37    US       FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you, that does exactly what I need it to. The only thing I have changed is to put it into the tidyverse format so that `dt` doesn't need to be repeated 3 times `dt %>% mutate(desc = Reduce(`|`, lapply(., grepl, pattern = "Glas")) & Reduce(`|`, lapply(., grepl, pattern = "Ann")))`